# Particle system issue - hair moves at the start of animation even without force fields

Tags: particles, workflow, force-fields

I have a sphere with a hair particle system.
gravity ON, stiffness 2.500, cache start: -200

I tried to play my animation without force field enabled, the particle system is moving (for sure it could be the gravity influence).
How can I see if I set the cache start at -200 the problem is still there or not.

How can I stop this animation and then be able to move the particle system without problems?

Comment: please edit the title of the question to be more specific to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking... but if you move to frame 0 it will reset it, unlike moving to frame 1.

Hope this solves the issue you were having!

Comment: i'd like to stop the initial movement of the particle system that i don't want.